# Wordpress Contact Foprm 7

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a label, but when I put [clock] it doesn't work for me. I am creating a plugin with the boilerplate template. Do you know why? Thank you!

class-rncf.php

```
private function define_admin_hooks() {

    $plugin_admin = new Rncf_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wpcf7_init', $plugin_admin, 'rnfc_init' );

}
```

class-rncf-admin.php

```
public function rnfc_init(){

    function custom_add_form_tag_clock() {
        wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'clock', 'custom_clock_form_tag_handler' ); // "clock" is the type of the form-tag
    }

    function custom_clock_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
        return date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: in the function `rnfc_init` called by action `wpcf7_init`, you cannot add another hook at `wpcf7_init` with the same priority. in the function `rnfc_init` try to call directly `wpcf7_add_form_tag(...`.

Comment: He removed the / add_action ('wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_form_tag_clock'); But it's not working